# Jquery, onBlur - if not empty show an alert

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to modify some other code that I found on SO, but it's not working (I'm still learning JQ)

My code:

```
  $("#Email").blur(function(){

  var inp = $("#Email").val();
  if(jQuery.trim(inp).length > 0)
  {
      alert("Yay!");
  }
  } );
```

Basically (in case it's not clear) I want to fire that alert() as the user moves away from the textbox - only if the user entered something in the textbox.

Comment: What's not working— is the `alert` being fired? https://jsfiddle.net/3vg2bcvt/4/

Comment: Code works, are you defining this handler in a doc.ready()?

Comment: Nope, alert was not being fired, I used the below answer and after adding the .ready() it works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code seems to work, make sure the field is loaded before binding the event, preferably using $(document).ready()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Email").blur(function(){

  var inp = $("#Email").val();
  if(jQuery.trim(inp).length > 0)
  {
      alert("Yay!");
  }
  } );
})
```

Here is the related [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s0djohua/)

Comment: Thanks! I think it was the .ready() that was the problem, I copied your code and it works :)